# How to insert points in a map

Tags: python, pandas

I have coordinates of some properties and I would like to insert the points of these properties in a map. I left an example below for you to see. Can you help me with this?

Executable code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
'Latitude':[-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
'Longitude':[-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702]})

print(df)

Properties Latitude Longitude 
0   1     -24.930473 -49.994889   
1   2     -24.955750 -49.990162   
2   3     -24.924161 -50.004343   
3   4     -24.955790 -50.007371   
4   5     -24.945570 -50.015420   
5   6     -24.932670 -50.007020
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: What research have you done? There should be existing libs that can do this, though I don't know of any myself. Maybe GeoPy or Seaborn?

Comment: Your problem is purely visualization of the data in the frame. If you are using Jupyter Notebooks, take a look at [gmaps](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps) which displays Google Maps in the notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use the Google Map API. However, it is not free. The othe way to do this is to use `folium` and OpenStreetMap.

```
import folium


df = pd.DataFrame({'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
'Latitude':[-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
'Longitude':[-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702]})

m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
m
```

The `m` will return a map of the world that is zoomable.

To add the markers to this:

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    folium.Marker(
      location=[df.iloc[i]['Latitude'], df.iloc[i]['Longitude']],
      popup=df.iloc[i]['Properties'],
   ).add_to(m)

m
```

will return:

[image]

[image]

You happened to put all your location near the Falkland Islands. You can zoom in as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks @Serge for replying. There is something wrong in the code because these coordinates are ok, they are located in a city in Brazil and not at sea. I tested another larger database with your code, and it gave the same result as yours, that is, something is incorrect in the code, I just don't know what.

Comment: Now I see, you put twice latitude in `location=[df.iloc[i]['Latitude'], df.iloc[i]['Latitude']]`

Comment: @Antonio Corrected. My bad! If it is what you wanted make sure to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for an open-source tool, have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)!   (based on matplotlib/cartopy)

Creting a quick map is as simple as:

```py
import pandas as pd
from eomaps import Maps

df = pd.DataFrame({'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
'Latitude':[-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
'Longitude':[-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702]})

m = Maps()
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m2.set_data(df, parameter="Properties", x="Latitude", y="Longitude", crs=4326)
m2.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=600) # use 600m circles to represent the data
m2.plot_map()
```

... or if you want to do more fancy stuff:

```py
import pandas as pd
from eomaps import Maps

df = pd.DataFrame({'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
'Latitude':[-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
'Longitude':[-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702]})


clat, clon = df.Latitude.mean(), df.Longitude.mean()

# create a map
m = Maps(Maps.CRS.Orthographic(clat, clon), figsize=(7,4))
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()

# create a zoomed-in inset-map
m2 = m.new_inset_map(xy=(clat, clon), 
                     radius=0.4, shape="rectangles", radius_crs=4326,
                     plot_position=(0.25, 0.5), plot_size=0.8)
# add some features and the data to the inset-plot
m2.add_wms.GEBCO.add_layer.GEBCO_LATEST()
m2.set_data(df, parameter="Properties", x="Latitude", y="Longitude", crs=4326)
m2.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=600)
m2.plot_map()

# adjust the subplot boundaries (e.g. to make the globe smaller)
m.subplots_adjust(left=0.5, right=1, top=0.8, bottom=0.2)

# add a basic annotation
m.add_annotation(xy=(clat, clon), 
                 xytext=(10,20),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 text="points are here", 
                 bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="r", ec="k", alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I left installing this package a long time ago, but it's not finished yet. I did it like this: `conda install -c conda-forge eomaps`. Hope it works, then I will test your code.

Comment: hey, to speed up the installation process a lot, use `mamba` as described in the docs [here](https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#installation)! (It is a drop-in c++ reimplementation of conda capable of solving complex environments a lot faster)  ... It usually gets you from hours to less than a minute :-)